# Checkboxes That Generate Images

Tags: javascript, css, image, checkbox, leftalign

I need help with a script that when I check a checkbox it generates an image (or multiple images if multiple checkboxes are selected).

I think I have this part down but I need the script to keep the checkboxes to the left side of the images and when I add more checkboxes (like 20 or 30 more) the first images doesn't start after the last checkbox. I need the images to start at the top of the webpage.

My current code is below:

You can play with the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/psyho/nrdnx/

Comment: keep in mind that one should include the code in the post because links die and/or people don't always want to leave this website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put the checkboxes and images in a container like so: http://jsfiddle.net/nrdnx/9/ I hope this helps, as I wasn't completely sure about what you were asking.

Comment: @Drawdesign, sorry I wasn't more clear...but you nailed it anyway. You're a saint. Thanks!

Comment: thanks so much for your answer, it worked perfectly but I was wondering is there a way to "Save" the changes I make when selecting the checkboxes? Currently if I select a checkbox and it generates an image, as soon as I leave my site and come back the changes are gone. I'm sure that's a beginner question but I can't seem to find the answer on this form. Many thanks in advance!